# github: initiate code review without pull request?

Tags: github, github-codereviews

it is a bad way to do code reviews after pull request has been initiated. sometimes we want to do code reviews before the whole thing is ready for integration. is there any tools out there that will allow code review without pull request? I prefer cloud based solution such as reviewable but it only works with pull request...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It really doesn’t matter if it’s a real issue with GitHub. That is irrelevant in this case. I read every word of your question. Please read the [help] before posting so you can learn what questions are allowed on Stack Overflow and which aren’t.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fastforward to 2019. Github now offers "draft pull requests":

https://github.blog/2019-02-14-introducing-draft-pull-requests/

Answer (score 1):

WIP (Work in Progress) pull requests are pretty common. GitHub doesn't have a built-in feature like GitLab or Gerrit have, but it's pretty easy to just do this by consensus: Open a PR that's prefixed with `WIP:` to indicate it isn't ready for being merged, but is open to feedback, and keep updating it (with `git push --force` most probably) as you go. Once you're done, you can remove the `WIP:` prefix.

**EDIT:**

While it isn't a built-in feature, the [WIP](https://github.com/apps/wip) third party app seems to help automate this for you, and prevent you from merging a WIP branch by mistake.